# Adding gradle dependency for pd for android in my gradle file does nothing

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, libpd

I am trying to import pd-for-android into my project as a gradle dependancy as per the instructions on [pd-for-android's githubpage](https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android) (i.e. make sure `jcenter()` is in the top level repositories in `build.gradle`, then add `compile 'org.puredata.android:pd-core:1.0.1'` to your dependancies in the app `build.gradle`)

I followed these instructions but I cannot see the library downloading into my external libraries. Is there something else i need to do in order to get this working?

here's my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            ...
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:+'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:+'
    compile 'org.puredata.android:pd-core:1.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if It's `inside app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\`

[image]

If you have there the library, you shouldn't have any problem to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it was indeed under that tab, I was always relying on the 'External Libraries' at the bottom of the list!

Answer (score 0):

Does it show up correctly as dependency when you click File->Project Structure and then on the dependencies tab in Android Studio?
if not, have you tried to add it there via the "+" Button?